# Cross platform synchronisation using Facebook in Unity

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

So I am developing this RPG mobile game in Unity with a lot of coins and firearms and purchases and the like. I want to allow the user to carry their achievements to another device (synch), should they decide to change their device or whatever, so they won't have to start everything from the very beginning. I know this is possible using Facebook SDK, but don't know how. Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a database? Username can be the e-mail - that way he can login on any device with the same username and gets all the data related to his game account.
Same is with Facebook as you suggested, he logs-in with his account (e-mail) and gets the accounts data.

If you don't have a database and store everything locally, you could store it to a file and then transfer the file to another system - that would be the simplest manual approach (but not recommended).